# query all users in an OU within Active Directory and output usernames to listbox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

I'm needing to modify a custom attribute we've added to the schema, but on an all user basis. The attribute is an MD5 hash, that I'm already storing as a public variable. I'm trying to get a list of all users within specified OU to be listed within the listbox so that you can select all the users or individual users to have the values applied to.

Here is my current code for Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.DirectoryServices;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        String Password;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Password = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Password);
            bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
            System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in bs)
            {
                s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
            }
            Password = s.ToString();

            textBox2.Text = Password;


        }   

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I go about getting all the users, not just specific ones, but all and get that info into an array or something that can be displayed within the listbox

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// List of strings for your names
List<string> allUsers = new List<string>();

// create your domain context and define the OU container to search in
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME", 
                                            "OU=SomeOU,dc=YourCompany,dc=com");

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal (user)
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   allUsers.Add(found.DisplayName);
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: so, is "ctx" the value by which i'm searching the users for? also, how can i get the values found into an array or something that i can put into a listbox? thanks

Comment: @Jeff Clay: Updated my response - you basically need to put some information (I picked the "DisplayName") for each user found in your container into e.g. a `List<string>` and then bind this to your listbox

Comment: Awesome, thanks. One more thing... How do I go about binding with my AD server to be able to query this info?

Comment: @Jeff Clay: the "binding" happens when the `PrincipalContext` is created. If you need to, you can specify a username/password in the constructor of the `PrincipalContext`.